# Bilateral filter doesn't have any improvement on image

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

So I have a clear image:

[image: Noisy image]

I'm using bilateral filter to denoise that, first I contaminate it with AWGN noise with var=0.01, here is my code:

```
import cv2 
from skimage.util import random_noise
img = cv2.imread('color/t156.png')
img=cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
img=random_noise(img,var=0.01).astype(np.float32)
sigmaColor = 50
sigmaSpace = 50
bilateral = cv2.bilateralFilter(img, 3, sigmaColor/255, sigmaSpace/255) 
f, axarr = plt.subplots(1,2)
axarr[0].imshow(img)
axarr[1].imshow(bilateral)
axarr[1].set_title(f"sigmaColor={sigmaColor/255:.2f},sigmaSpace={sigmaSpace/255:.2f}")
f.tight_layout()
```

The problem is that there is almost no change in output, no matter how I change SigmaColor or SigmaSpatial. It's even some how worse visually!!!
I guess there might be something wrong with code but I'm not sure where is the problem.

[image: Output]
I tried different images and parameters for BF filter but nothing changed.

I even tried with a simple image:
[image]

This is quite smooth so I expect a good output:

```
import cv2 
from skimage.util import random_noise
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math
def psnr(img1,img2):

  img1 = img1.astype(np.float64)
  img2 = img2.astype(np.float64)
  mse = np.mean((img1 - img2) ** 2)
  psnr=10 * np.log10(1. / mse)
  return psnr
  
img = cv2.imread('fin.jpg',0).astype(np.float32)/255
imgn=random_noise(img,var=0.01).astype(np.float32)
sigmaColor = 50
sigmaSpace = 50
bilateral = cv2.bilateralFilter(imgn, 10, sigmaColor/255, sigmaSpace/255) 
f, axarr = plt.subplots(1,2)
axarr[0].imshow(imgn,cmap='gray')
axarr[1].imshow(bilateral,cmap='gray')
axarr[1].set_title(f"PSNR={psnr(bilateral,img):.2f},sigmaColor={sigmaColor/255:.2f},sigmaSpace={sigmaSpace/255:.2f}")
f.tight_layout()
```

And the output is:

[image: Output]

This is ridiculous! I'm sure there is something wrong.

Comment: You set `d=3` in the call to `bilateralFilter`. That is tiny, and means that the spatial sigma becomes irrelevant. Set it much larger, at least 9 but maybe 15 or more. Or set it to 0 to let the spatial sigma dictate the filter size (ideal).

Comment: @CrisLuengo I tried with d=0 but still the same problem is here, even for black and white image I showed in last, the same problem is still there.

Comment: Then increase the spatial sigma. You’re using 50/255? That’s less than one pixel! Try 2 or 4 instead.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Well, the problem is that I never cannot get a PSNR above 24 or 25 for the black and white image at the end of my question, which I believe is a very simple image and shouldn't be that hard to get a good PSNR, I tried what you said but now the edges are completely ruined, it's almost the same as applying gaussian now.

Comment: Then make `sigmaColor` smaller. It is what decides which colors to merge and which to keep separate. The smaller it is, the more edges are preserved.